# Regex for .htaccess excluding URL from redirect because of occurrence day in URL

Tags: regex

What I'm trying to do is to create a regex for matching URL's with this structure:

```
http://example.com/2016/01/sample-post-title/
```

and not matching structure of:

```
http://example.com/2016/01/31/
http://example.com/2016/01/page/sample-post-title/
http://example.com/2016/01/31/page/sample-post-title/
```

Now I've got such a Regex structure:

```
^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$
```

but it matches links from the first URL exception example. What should I add to regex to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe [`^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!\d+/|page/)(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/tU5dV6/1) will help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't match the http://example.com/2016/01/sample-post-title/ structure.

Comment: But it is matched in my demo, isn't it?

Comment: Yup its working. Sorry for misunderstanding but in my app there were a rewriter rule somewhere else and it was messing up redirect on my test link.

Comment: So, should I post with explanations or is Vegeta's answer OK for you (no explanations are necessary)? I dislike "try-this" answers, but I do not want to impose my tastes on anyone. :)

Comment: Explanations are good :D
Thank You very much for answering and me and other users appreciate explanations but I had to quickfix something and I there were no time to improve my regex knowledge, so in this situation any working answer was good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/sample-post-title.*$
```

or

```
\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/(?!page|\d+).*$
```

Comment: Its probbably working. Sorry for misunderstanding but in my app there were a rewriter rule somewhere else and it was messing up redirect on my test link.